# html: how to change list from unordered list to ordered list

Tags: javascript, html

I want to convert unordered list of elements to ordered list with strikethrough text based on the condition for each individual item in the list.
It is possible?

My current code:

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li v-bind:class="{ is_valid: contains_eight_characters }"> Minimum 8 Characters</li>
  <span> Include any three of the following</span>
  <li v-bind:class="{ is_valid: contains_number }">Contains Number</li>
  <li v-bind:class="{ is_valid: contains_uppercase }">Contains Uppercase</li>
  <li v-bind:class="{ is_valid: contains_lowercase }">Contains Lowercase</li>
  <li v-bind:class="{ is_valid: contains_special_character }">Contains Special Character</li> 
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
is_valid~li:before { 
     content:"\2714\0020"; 
     text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

I think i don't have the right syntax to update the `li:before` class after the `is_valid` property is turned on.

Please advise.

**Update**

Changing the css to

```
ul {
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    li.is_valid:before { 
         content:"\2714\0020"; 
         text-decoration: line-through;
    }
```

Now the UI looks like this:
[image]

The strike through is not going through the complete text.

**Expected result:**

Once the is_valid is true, the list element will convert a ordered list element with 'check icon' instead of bullet and the text would be striked.

**Current result:**

Once the is_valid is true, the list element is converting a ordered list element with 'check icon' instead of bullet and the check icon is striked but not the text.

Comment: `is_valid~li:before` -> `li.is_valid:before`

Comment: it looks like you're using a framework. Which one? Is it vue.js?

Comment: @code_monk yes.Its vue.js

Comment: @dave I added the image, change to `li.is_valid:before` is not striking through the complete text. It is just striking the 'tick'. I want the text to be striked and not the 'tick' of the ordered list.

Comment: so move the strike through to a block `li.is_valid { text-decoration: line-through; }`

Comment: I'll quibble with your structure a little — it seems to me that "Minimum 8 Characters"  and "Include any three of the following" isn't/shouldn't-be part of the list, the list is what _follows_ "Include any three of the following". A small quibble, but it would change your CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to have an ordered list inside of an unordered list, that's two lists. Something like this.

```css
li.is_valid {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

li.is_valid:before { 
  content:"\2714\0020";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li v-bind:class="{ is_valid: contains_eight_characters }"> Minimum 8 Characters</li>
  <li>
    <span> Include any three of the following</span>
    <ol>
      <li v-bind:class="{ is_valid: contains_number }">Contains Number</li>
      <li v-bind:class="{ is_valid: contains_uppercase }">Contains Uppercase</li>
      <li v-bind:class="{ is_valid: contains_lowercase }">Contains Lowercase</li>
      <li v-bind:class="{ is_valid: contains_special_character }">Contains Special Character</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: NO, its one list. It is unordered at first then based on condition it should convert to order list with a tick icon instead of bullet and the text should be striked.

Comment: Ordered vs unorderd is set on the list, not the list item. You don't need to change the list type to change the way the marker in front of it looks, though. You can use the ::marker pseudo-element to style it. Try ul ::marker { *styles* } and see where you get.

Answer (score 0):

first, change UL to OL
then go over the list with a input.onKeyUp event (javascript) and correct the styling of each list item

heres some pseudo code that may help

```
var items = document.getElementById("olYouWant");
for (var x = 0; x < items.getElementsByTagName("LI").length; x++){
  items.getElementsByTagName("LI")[x].style = "text-decoration:strikethrough";
}
```